# PowerShell: Script throwing up in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

When run in `-Parallel`, the following script does not pass the `$basePath` variable declared before the start of the parallel block. Instead, it is a null value. This is not a problem when the script is not run in `-Parallel` -- it will pass the variable value and run as expected. FYI, I am running PS 7.x.

```
$basePath=((get-location) -replace "\\", "\\")
get-childitem *.tif -recurse | foreach-object -Parallel {
    $a=($_ -split "\.tif")[0]
    $path=(((split-path $_) -replace "$basePath", "O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Family Photos") -replace "TIF", "JPG")
    $b=(($a -replace "$basePath", "O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Family Photos") -replace "TIF", "JPG")
    if (!(Test-Path -path $path)) {mkdir "$path"}
    if (!([system.io.file]::Exists("$b.jpg"))) {
        magick convert "$a.tif" -resize 50% -quality 100 -define jpeg:extent=1024KB "$b.jpg"
        [console]::foregroundcolor="Green"
        echo "`nB`:`t$b`n`n"
    }
} -ThrottleLimit 8
    [console]::foregroundcolor="White"
```

Comment: put `$using:` in front of each reference to $basepath and drop the leading $ from the var name. I'll answer as to why thats needed once we determine it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in powershells new `-parallel` scheme, you need to use `$using:basePath` instead of just `$basePath` for all invocations inside the parallel loop. This is because the variable is defined in a parent scope.

Multi-threading and parallel operations present a unique set of complications collectively referred to as Concurrency or multi-concurrent issues, and thus require special steps be taken to assure that memory accessed by threads is in a safe state for use.

Powershell implements a threaded context called a RunSpace, and creates one for each parallel operation. The runspace contains a copy of every variable declared in that block, and can only operate on those copied instances of the variables. this means that if one thread modifies their version of the variable, other threads will not see that change.

In order to access a variable that is in-scope for multiple threads however, we must look into techniques like Mutex's and Locks. A thread lock is a simple construct that prevents a value from being modified while it is being used. In Powershell, they made that easy, by adding the `$using:` keyword for referencing variables of higher-scope.

See here for more details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I appreciate the additional reading.